# No `typer` after building and installing Erlang/OTP

Tags: erlang

I built and installed [OTP-20.2.2](https://github.com/erlang/otp/tree/OTP-20.2.2) on Fedora 27 following the [instructions](http://erlang.org/doc/installation_guide/INSTALL.html).

After installation, however, there doesn't seem to be a [`typer`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/typer.html) executable. Everything else (`erl`, `dialyzer`, etc.) seems to be there.

`brew install erlang` on a Mac also doesn't give a `typer` executable.

Does something special need to be done to get `typer`?

Comment: what do you mean by `typer executable`. Isn't it in the path?

Comment: No. It's not under `/usr/local/bin`, which is where `erl`, `dialyzer` etc. are.

Answer (score 0):

Since OTP-20, you should find the executable file : typer.beam in the directory erl9.X/lib/dialyzerY-Z/ebin. In previous versions it was in its own directory.